# Numbering the List View of the SE Sites site?

Tags: feature-request, site-stats

In addition to using many of the moderator analytics tools, which I review several times a week, I sometimes look at the [List View of the SE Sites site](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday) to gain insight into some other characteristics of the two sites I moderate.

The page is very useful because it enables me to sort by various criteria (e.g. Questions Per Day, Percent Answered, Users, etc) to get an inter-site view of things.  When sites that I would expect to be at least superficially similar to ours appear much higher/lower it can be helpful to think about why that might be.

However, after each sort I find myself counting down the sites and scrolling the pages to try and figure where the one I am interested in is currently ranked by that criteria.

Could we have a ranking number, that updates when the criteria is switched, added as a column on the list displayed i.e. perhaps like in the picture below but much more neatly?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I downvoted because I think this would be a worse than meaningless statistic. All sites are so different that deliberately comparing these criteria is likely to make you focus on the wrong thing. Your site make up is different to every other one.

I moderate a few sites, and what is much more useful in terms of assessing health is looking at the various admin graphs with the x axis starting at Public Beta or Graduation, and looking at the growth curves.

The absolute numbers are different across sites, but the shape of the graphs is a very good indicator of health and success. I review mine weekly (or thereabouts)

The graphs also give you a good idea of seasonality - eg Outdoors.SE follows the weather, Music.SE has peaks that seem to follow term times etc.