# Network-wide site comparison statistics

Tags: feature-request, badges, statistics, site-stats, network-statistics

It seems to me that different sites on the Stack Exchange network are very different when it comes to statistics such as average views per question, reputation per user, badges per user, etc. I would really love to see a page with statistics of various Stack Exchange sites presented in a nice way. We already have [this page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but there is very little data provided on the site list (only one of my below suggestions is included) and the Data Explorer requires you to be searching for a specific piece of data. I'm suggesting a page with presented data analysis.

A few possibilities:

- For the average user, comparing numbers of questions, answers, reputation, and gold/silver/bronze badges
- For the average question, comparing views, votes, shares, and answers
- Proportions of questions that are unanswered, have no upvotes, etc.
- Proportion of site traffic from Google searches as opposed to site searches or navigation
- Where are users/visitors from?
- How much use does each meta site get compared to its main site?

This is obviously a low-priority suggestion, but I think it would be really fascinating!

Comment: Oops, a near-duplicate of [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175118/can-we-have-a-useless-statistics-site), though that is more specifically addressing single questions and answers, and I'm looking more for site-wide data.

Comment: This is far less ambitious feature request on site stats that I expected to be better received: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244812/numbering-the-list-view-of-the-se-sites-site

Comment: FWIW, it is possible to extract #1, #2, #3, and #6 from the Data Explorer through dynamic SQL (assuming you provide a more precise definition of "amount of use" for #6), though I don't have time to do so now. Perhaps @rene will stumble by and work his SQL magic.

Comment: @senshin True, but I'd like to be able to look at a visual representation, if possible, which I don't think is achievable with SEDE.

Comment: This would probably be interesting, but I doubt we'd have the bandwidth to work on it unless without a demonstrated need / use case for it (I think you know that, since you mentioned this would be low priority). A lot of data is public though, so anyone with an interest and the right skills could do some of that digging.