# List of most popular SE sites (based on questions asked)?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Does anyone have a list of all Stack Exchange sites in order? (Based off of questions asked.)

I know Stack Overflow is the most popular in those terms.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions

Comment: @Pang doesn't really tell the exact order though.

Comment: What exact order do you want? Use the `"Sort by"` dropdown on that page.

Comment: That link does order by the total number of questions, descending. It's perfectly in order.

Comment: @ Ben N  ok. Just forgot to click that. Thank you @Pang

Comment: You may also be looking for how to number those sites after sorting them: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244812/215590

Comment: Can this be community wiki?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to answer that question. This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/497343) uses a multi-database procedure to visit each database and run some basic stats:

```sql
-- start create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      -- we have three sites that have borked DNS entries
      set @dbname = (case @dbname
      when 'StackExchange.Audio' then 'StackExchange.Avp'
      when 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta' then 'StackExchange.Avp.Meta'
      when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' then 'net.Mathoverflow.meta'
      else @dbname
      end)
      -- and one of those doesn't want to end with .com
      if @dbname <> 'net.Mathoverflow.meta' 
         set @dbname = 'com.' + @dbname
      exec #recursesiteurl @dbname,  @res OUTPUT
   end
GO
-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#recursesiteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #recursesiteurl;
GO
create procedure #recursesiteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
       
      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #recursesiteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
GO

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE
                         and ([name] not like '%.Meta' or [name] = 'StackExchange.Meta')

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_stats ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , qcount int
                            , acount int
                            , ccount int
                            , ucount int);
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_stats 
               select @url
               , (select count(*) from posts where posttypeid=1)
               , (select count(*) from posts where posttypeid=2)
               , (select count(*) from comments)
               , (select count(*) from users)
               ;'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select replace(
       replace(
       replace(site,
         '.StackExchange.com',''),
         '.com',''),
         '.net','') as [site]
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '|'
     + site as link
     , qcount as [# Questions]
     , acount as [# Answers]
     , ccount as [# Comments]
     , ucount as [# Users]
from #all_stats
order by qcount desc

drop table #all_stats

drop procedure #recursesiteurl
drop procedure #siteurl
```

When run today the result looks like this:

[image]

Based on the suggestion of [Peter Mortensen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280041/list-of-most-popular-se-sites-based-on-questions-asked/280050?noredirect=1#comment930384_280050) it would be more *fair* if a question rate was used, I assumed rate to mean Question/total days. That doesn't make a lot of difference:

[image: qrate per total days]

Comment: That is a little bit unfair to young sites compared to the eight-year-old gorilla. That is, scaling by site age could be interesting (essentially getting answer rates, question rates, etc.). It may not be easy to accomplish using SEDE, though.

Comment: @PeterMortensen if that is just questions / #days site exists then it is not hard at all.

Answer (score 2):

As @Pang commented, you can visit [All Sites - Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questions) and you can sort by

Traffic, Oldest, Newest, Questions, Answers, Percent Answered, Users, Questions Per Day, Name.