# Why did I lose 5 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something but I randomly lost 5 rep.[image]

Clicking that brings me here
[image: l]

My user wasn't removed because I can look at my profile and stuff. Can someone tell me why this happened?

Comment: Someone upvoted your question, and later had their account deleted, and in doing so, all their votes revoked, causing you to lose 5 rep from that upvote getting revoked. That was not random.

Comment: Their upvote was revoked when their account was deleted so you lost five rep from that upvote getting revoked.

Comment: @John But I still have the same amounts of up votes on my other two questions

Comment: Probably a bug that they have the same number of upvotes.

Comment: Or maybe an upvote on a deleted question was revoked do to removal.

Comment: @John That would make sense, but I haven't answered any questions on Stack Exchange

Comment: I'm talking about **your** deleted question, not an answer you posted to a deleted question.

Comment: @John I don't have any deleted questions!!!

Comment: As I said, it might be a bug that a vote wasn't removed from one of your questions.

Comment: @John It could be a bug... but a simpler explanation is that there weren't any other votes to revoke. ;)

Comment: Does this mean that deleting a post with a negative score will give me back my lost rep?

Comment: @Adamawesome4 I think so, don't quote me on that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user who upvoted [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280041/list-of-most-popular-se-sites-based-on-questions-asked) of yours was deleted.

This has nothing to do with any of your other questions since that person didn't vote on them one way or another (although downvotes on questions wouldn't affect your rep anyway and would just be removed silently).

For what it's worth, on the [desktop version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/324325/alex?tab=reputation) of the reputation page we also link to [this Help Center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed) that should help explain how user deletion can affect your reputation.

Comment: @zaq wat. This is why we can't have nice things. I guess there's sort of a precedent for showing which post lost rep (it's not secret per se, but doesn't carry much useful information either except for pure curiosity - unless, of course, voter spoke up in comments or something). Either way, I'm comfortable declining these requests if/when they come up and revealing the deleted user is 100% right out of the question.